# String formatting in Python -textwrapper

Tags: python, string-formatting, word-wrap

I have a list of `People=[Tom,Mike,Carol]` and I want to print it in the the below format.

```
People    Tom
          Mike
          Carol
```

Basically its the Title (People) some fixed tabs and then a list of the name in  new line ( it sorta looks like a table). I want to achieve this using textwrap in Python but if there is any other possibility, I am open to that as well.

```
dedented_text = textwrap.dedent(' This is a test sentecne to see how well   the textwrap works and hence using it here to test it').strip()
for width in [ 20 ]:
    h='{0: <4}'.format('f')
    k='{0: >4}'.format(textwrap.fill(dedented_text, width=20))
    print h+k
```

Output:

```
f   This is a test
sentecne to see how
well the textwrap
works and hence
using it here to
test it
```

Above i added my code for printing the Category and a sentence. But i'm not able to achieve what I want

Comment: @BhargavRao : Sorry, forgot to add that

Answer (score 0):

Just print the first line separately then print the others in a loop:

```
print 'People ' + people[0]

for i in range(1, len(people)):
    print ' ' * 7 + people[i]
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if i also want to print the example sentence in the same fashion? I don't want the second line of the sentence to start from the edge of the screen.